# Is it possible to only handle remove command on FUSE mounted partitions?

Tags: c++, fuse

I have to use FUSE only to detect the remove command on the FUSE mounted partitions and do some operations on that and my purpose of using FUSE is only that

But it detects all file system calls and are channeled through FUSE. I need to avoid that..How ?

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you're asking; `FUSE` is a file system implementation for userland and as such you can choose to implement as much or little of it as you want, but at a minimum you probably need to implement `getattr` and `readdir` in order to see what you're trying to `unlink`; or is this some layer on top of `FUSE`?

Comment: What i want to do is only use xmp_unlink and remaining should go through system calls. Is there any alternative to find only unlink (rm) commands across partitions other than FUSE ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't *need* but would be fine with channeling all calls thru your fs, you could implement a mirroring filesystem. Search for [mirror in the FileSystems](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FileSystems) page to get started.

If that is no option, but still want to use FUSE, you might want to look into [related discussions](http://fuse.996288.n3.nabble.com/bypassing-read-write-for-mirror-fs-td2522.html) of how to channel selected system calls via the FUSE fs and others not (read/write in this case).

That is complicated, however, and probably quite some work, so you might want to drop the FUSE approach. If you don't need to veto the removal, a file monitoring approach might be simpler.